# Hide Columns in Breeze data returns

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

In our entity framework model that identify the customer, a simple Customer_GUID. We are using breeze with asp.net mvc and doing IQueryable.

Is there a way to globally not return those columns in the JSON? This would reduce a good bit of data coming across the wire. We don't want to remove it from mapping in our EF model because we still use it when we save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at [the Json.NET documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html) in particular the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute. Look at "Conditional Property Serialization" for more sophisticated scenarios.

Do be careful about insert and update data coming from the client. You'll have to do something if your client uploads a new entity for insertion and it lacks the properties you require on the server side.

To be clear, your configuration of Json.NET has no affect on your server-side EF model ... exactly what you wanted.

That also means that metadata generated from your EF model will describe properties the client can't see. You'll want to compensate for that I imagine. Such compensation is beyond the scope of this question; look to the Breeze documentation on metadata ... particularly ["Metadata by hand"](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/metadata-by-hand) and ["EF as a design tool"](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/ef-design-tool).